# Using INSERT INTO with a provided text string and a select * from another table

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to create a table that compiles multiple tables into one, and this new table will have a column which stores the name of the table each row is sourced from.

(I am compiling multiple time-series results from different time windows into one summary table, but the time-series label must be included as a new column)

I am using `pyscopg2` to pass queries to postgres via python, and the table name to be stored as text is created in and passed from Python.

My query is running on an isolated, local postgres database and therefore I am not worried about passing table names as parameters. Yes, I know this is bad form, but for now I just need to get this working.

pseudo code of what I hope to accomplish:

```
INSERT INTO destination_table VALUES ('string of source table name', select * from source_table)
```

It should be noted that the destination table has been created with the correct dimensions/data types to accept the data.
The names inside the `{}` are parameters I am passing from python.

Actual code that I have tried:

```
WITH upd as (SELECT many, columns, here… FROM {table_to_compile}  where dep_count >=4)
  INSERT INTO destination_table VALUES ('{table_to_compile}',(SELECT * from upd))
```

The above code returns an error that `"the sub selection query should only return one column"`.

I have tried different combinations using `INSERT INTO` but I will refrain from posting every query I have tested as I hope my goal has been clearly described.

Comment: Just a tip, to do code blocks use the ` which is right below the `esc` key. Not `'`. This usually trips up users new to markdown.

Comment: thanks for the tip! i'm wrestling with a foreign language kb right now and still finding my way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `values(expression, subquery)`, but you can add a constant to the select like this:

```
INSERT INTO destination_table
select 'string of source table name' as column_name, * 
from source_table;
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer was almost the perfect fix. I had to remove the word VALUES from the structure that you posted and then it worked. Thank you!

Comment: That's often the problem with writing suggestions without testing them. I'll edit the answer then and you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

So, you say 'I am trying to create a table that compiles multiple tables into one', this sounds like a Union Query to me.  To do an insert into SQL Server (just picking one example; I don't think you specified which database you are dealing with).  Here is a simple sample script to do the insert.

```
import pyodbc
user='sa'
password='PC#1234'
database='climate'
port='1433'
TDS_Version='8.0'
server='192.168.1.103'
driver='FreeTDS'

   con_string='UID=%s;PWD=%s;DATABASE=%s;PORT=%s;TDS=%s;SERVER=%s;driver=%s' % (user,password, database,port,TDS_Version,server,driver)
   cnxn=pyodbc.connect(con_string)
   cursor=cnxn.cursor()
   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mytable(name,address) VALUES (?,?)",('thavasi','mumbai'))
   cnxn.commit()
```

To do a Union, just substitute the correct SQL syntax into the `cursor.execute` statement.

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2
```

Comment: HI Asher, thanks for the reply but the issue has been solved. my challenge was not union-ing the tables, but actually inserting the name of the table being inserted as a static text string into its own respective column in the new table. @Coladict provided the correct code above. Admittedly, its basic SQL stuff, but i guess being self-taught means missing some basic tricks like this. Also, just FYI, the "tags" on the post specify the DB software i am using.

Comment: @Marshall I was self-taught before my formal education, but the real learning comes with reaching necessities like this in real-world practice, and sometimes with random experiments.